# Listen on multiple RPC ports

Tags: json-rpc

Running Ubuntu 17.10 server

bitcoin.conf contains a setting: `rpcport=<port>`

Is there any way to cause `bitcoind` (0.16) to listen on multiple RPC ports at the same time?

example: `rpcport=1234,1235,1236`

Currently, the wait-timeout prevents new connections to the RPC server until the old one times out. I want to avoid that by having clients use different ports.

If there is another (better) way to reduce/eliminate the wait-timeout, please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try and use iptables instead! Just forward the port secondary ports to the primary.

https://serverfault.com/questions/320614/how-to-forward-port-80-to-another-port-on-the-samemachine

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had considered this, but my concern is that if ports are redirected via iptables won't they still encounter the wait-timeout since they will reach the server on what it will detect as the same port? For example if the server is set to receive queries on port 8000, and I redirect port 8001 to port 8000, when a query comes in on 8000 and 8001 at the same time, the server will see them as two queries on 8000 and make one of them wait. Or am I incorrect? My goal is to cause the server to accept queries on multiple ports simultaneously..

Comment: The RPC can handle multiple connections at the same time. The parameters "-rpcthreads" sets the number of threads to service RPC calls (default: 4).